# systemd Firewall .service Unit: Type=exec or Type=oneshot?

Tags: shell-script, firewall, dependencies, systemd-unit, boot-process

I'm debugging a firewall .service unit and a few questions arise.

One of those questions is the unit's best service type, either exec or oneshot.  Virtually no comparisons of the two appear in my searches, probably because exec is a relatively recent addition to systemd (v.249 IIRC).

By way of background, the unit (call it iptables.service) is intended to activate and configure the firewall by running a Bash script (call it iptables.sh) before the network is up (*i.e.*, before network-pre.target), *e.g.*,

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/home/locsh/iptables.sh'
```

**Type=oneshot** has the advantage of not entering the "active" state, so it subsequently can be restarted or reactivated, *e.g.*, by a timer unit.  It also is the more common of the two types in most examples, albeit without explanation.

**Type=exec** has the advantage that it will delay startup of follow-up units until the main service has been executed.  This seems to make perfect sense for a firewall .service unit because the network should depend on the script running successfully and remain down otherwise, *e.g.*, if the script temporarily can't be read because somehow the relevant .mount unit hasn't yet activated.

**Restart=on-failure** seems to be an obvious and prudent addition in either case.

*The first question* is whether one or the other might better for any reason.

*The second question* is whether Type=exec, because it delays the start of follow-up units, might introduce a subtle ordering cycle in some edge cases, either with or without "Restart=on-failure", in part because the unit's ordering dependency

```
Before=network-pre.target
```

is relatively early in the boot process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `type=oneshot`. If you use `type=exec`, other services will be able to start before the firewall is configured. From the `systemd.service` man page, for `exec`:

> ...Or in other words: simple proceeds with further jobs right after fork() returns, while exec will not proceed before both fork() and execve() in the service process succeeded.

And for `oneshot`:

> Behavior of oneshot is similar to simple; however, the service manager will consider the unit up after the main process exits.

In other words, with `Type=exec`, `systemd` considers the service to
be "up" once the process has successfully *started*, while
for `Type=oneshot`, `systemd` considers the service to be "up" once
the process has successfully *completed*.

Comment: Also, both `Type=simple` and `Type=exec` will fundamentally assume that the `ExecStart=` process is supposed to keep running until the service is intentionally stopped, and will mark the service as failed if it dies on its own. If `Restart=on-failure` is added, that would mean the firewall script would run again and again, repeatedly, possibly causing periodic hiccups in network connectivity and certainly making any iptables/nftables statistics useless.

Comment: @telcoM, am I correct that you don't see any difficulty with `Restart=on-failure` if `Type=oneshot`?

Comment: Just that if it failed once, it is likely to fail again, if the failure is caused by something like a typo. That might cause an infinite loop where you cannot easily access the system because networking, `sshd` and console logins are not yet up.